# Is there a 1/2 Female copper to 3/4 Pex barb adapter?

Tags: plumbing

I need to connect a 3/4" PEX pipe to an 1/2" copper pipe.
The copper end of the adapter must be a female type
Is there an adapter for this ? Can't find anything like it. Useg Google and Amazon.ca ...maybe I am not using the right key words, I am not familiar with the plumbing terminology

Comment: Both of those to 1/2" pipe thread are easy to come by, so pop a threaded joint in the middle and you're good.

Comment: this will be behind a wall so I am reluctant to add more couplings than I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called a "1/2 in. Brass Female Sweat Copper Adapter x 3/4 in. Pex Barb Pipe Fitting"

[Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/The-Plumber-s-Choice-1-2-in-Brass-Female-Sweat-Copper-Adapter-x-3-4-in-Pex-Barb-Pipe-Fitting-5-Pack-12345PSFA/308872572) | [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08CC2YHPB)

[image]

Sidenote: it took me quite some time to become efficient for searching these kinds of parts.

---

Per your comment this part is unavailable to you so you can do this:

- Get a [1/2" female sweat to 1/2" barbed adapter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Apollo-1-2-in-Brass-PEX-Barb-x-1-2-in-Female-Copper-Sweat-Adapter-APXFS1212/301541045)

  - If available then do a [1/2" push-to-connect coupling](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-Brass-Coupling-Fitting-U008LFA/202270492) instead since it will help to avoid soldering
- Attach a short (6-12 inches) piece of 1/2" pex
- Get a [3/4" to 1/2" barbed transition](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Apollo-3-4-in-x-1-2-in-Brass-PEX-Barb-Reducing-Coupling-APXC1234/301541091)

  - Not sure about your pipe layout but a [3/4" to 1/2" barbed elbow](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-3-4-in-x-1-2-in-PEX-Barb-Brass-90-Degree-Reducing-Elbow-Fitting-UC274LFA/202270597) could be a better choice
  - [3/4" x 3/4" x 1/2" reducing tee](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-4-in-x-3-4-in-x-1-2-in-Brass-PEX-Barb-Reducing-Tee-APXT343412/301541251) could also be used depending on where this transition is

Comment: Hmm Amazon.ca and Homedepot.ca don't seem to carry these

Comment: re: your side note -yes I am a DIYer and I am having a hard time with sourcing these as everybody is channeling their money into renos these days. Went to specialized stored and many parts were out of stock

Comment: @MiniMe Yeah, I think this is why shopping-specific questions are generally off-topic. If you could share a basic diagram of your pipe layout then it could help to provide better suggestions. However, please see the edits I've made.

Comment: Is this what I am looking for or it is the reverse (3/4" copper to 1/2" pex) ? https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/pex-female-sweat-coupling-adapter-1-2-in-x-3-4-in-0631389p.0631389.html

Comment: @MiniMe Unfortunately that site does not offer a picture of the dimensions like Home Depot but comparing the pictures it seems to be the correct 3/4" barbed to 1/2" sweat adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a 1/2" to 3/4" push-to-connect adapter? It should handle both of those types of piping. This would allow you connect the two bare ends of the two pipes.

https://www.amazon.ca/Coupling-Group-Connect-Fitting-Straight/dp/B08GB88WTD/ref=mp_s_a_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=push+to+connect+fittings+1%2F2+3%2F4&qid=1619046220&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFVT1pQSUNKRTdFUk0mZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA1NTYwNzkzMUhOTzdCUUdXTEY2JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTEwNDY3MzIxSENFWFA1TjROTFlOJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfcGhvbmVfc2VhcmNoX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=

Comment: that is a sharkbite like connector right ? this will be behind the wall I do not want any problems

Comment: It is a sharkbite style connector. I'd trust a push-to-connect fitting being installed correctly more than trying to get a wall adjacent copper/brass fitting soldered well. Especially in a diy situation where the person my not be comfortable with using a propane torch.

Comment: hmmm that is a good point but the pipes that I am connecting to are vertical going downward are like 1" away from the wall (they used to feed the shower/tub that I am relocating). The couplers will be soldered with the coupling piece upside so they will hold the melted aluminum and I will be able to pressure test by turning the water on and leave them under pressure till I finish everything

Comment: I happy with all my P2C fittings I've been using for the last 10 years. I've had none fail me after initial testing. I just did a similar bath room job as you.