# Is there a push in 1/2"x3/8" MNPT coupling?

Tags: plumbing

I have this shower column https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/SH-PN-7001BN.pdf
It has 3/8" hoses that connect to a 3/8" MPT connectors
I am trying to improvise a stub out solution with an 1/2"x3/8" push in coupling attached to the below stub out elbow.

I can't find any 1/2"x3/8" MNPT push in coupling

[image]

The shower column hose connector looks like this (also see the PDF)

[image]

Comment: Is this a dupe of [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222679/is-there-a-1-2-female-copper-to-3-4-pex-barb-adapter) or a follow on? You may want to clarify that point.

Comment: Perhaps you meed a plumber given the amount of issues you have with pex and copper.

Comment: Why are trying to improvise a "*push in coupling*"  instead of  soldering on the correct threaded  adapter to accept the hose fittings of the unit? I assume that there are specific instruction that came with the unit on how to connect to the supply lines.

Comment: the above linked manual is all I have for the shower
@FreeMan : it is part of the same design but a different problem; that thread is the transition from copper to pex for the entire bathroom. 
This thread is the stub out solution for the shower

Comment: I still can not see what the problem is. You have a Pex barb on the supply side of the stub out to accept the Pex supply line. The end of the Pex is  expanded/pushed or just pushed (*different methods*) onto the barb and then a crimp ring is crimped on to secure it. You have copper on the stub out side to solder on the proper threaded connection for the hose's of the shower unit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U6mD0cpDkg - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E22gIQAPPbI

Comment: I do not want to solder anything if possible

Comment: In my experience, if you don't want to do any soldering, you're going to end up with incomplete plumbing. Granted, I haven't done _major_ plumbing in quite a number of years, but all the tub fixtures I installed required some sort of soldered connections.

Comment: trying to keep it down as much as possible. I am working with pex and I will still have to solder the transitions from copper to pex

Comment: @MiniMe  No you do not have to "*solder the transitions from copper to pex*" That is crimp connection. Pex on/over the barb and crimp.  **Did you watch the videos i linked to on how to work with pex?** For the stub out  you can use  a compression fitting on the copper.

Comment: transition from the supply lines which is 1/2" copper to PEX needs an adapter, that needs to be soldered there is no way around as far as I could see (unless I use push ins behind the wall, an idea that I don't like)