# Would a 1/2x3/8 Dishwasher Tube to Pipe Elbow, 90 take a 3/8 flex connect for a shower pannel?

Tags: plumbing

To give an example [here](https://www.amazon.ca/SharkBite-U281LFA-Dishwasher-2-Inch-8-Inch/dp/B007AGPX90?th=1) is such an Sharkbite elbow and here is what I know about the supply lines of my shower panel. The shower panel manual is [here](https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/SH-PN-7001BN.pdf)

Update: Please if this does not work point me to a similar elbow (compression or push in) that will work. This will sit out of the wall behind the shower pannel

[image]

And this is the elbow
[image]

Here is a picture of the shower end
[image]

Update: the picture showing the thread and the plastic cap attached to it

[image]
[image]

Fits perfect on this guy
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this will not work, the elbow has a courser thread

Comment: Can you post a pic of the thread in the nut? Will that nut thread onto a standard 1/2" pipe? What country are you in (I ask because common plumbing fitting sizes could vary by area)?

Comment: I am in Canada, the thread it eh one typical for flexible connectors, finer than the one in the picture

Comment: picture uploaded

Comment: @MiniMe This seems to be another version of this question. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222731/is-there-a-push-in-1-2x3-8-mnpt-coupling#comment419798_222731

Comment: Why are you  trying to avoid A standard supply line  to shower unit plumbing connection set up? (*1/2" copper or Pex*) The dishwasher  plumbing as a **very small inner diameter**, this will have a drastic impact on the water pressure of the shower unit.

Comment: I am not sold to that fitting, It was suggested to me that I could use that. I need something that can accommodate the above shower hose connector and that is either push in or compression. It has to be elbow as the shower panel is 3" deep and a straight fitting will stick out of the wall too much with the shower intake connector on top

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51Z1Xb5n6F0 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBM1S700QU8 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRvGgC_jCxA

Comment: I knew of the first two videos, the third was new to me. I must say that the second one looks fishy with that hole left wide open behind the panel. One thing to note that these units all seem to have 1/2" like hose size while mine is 3/8" I am wondering why. I could of course change those hoses and in this respect I am happy that I decided to use shark bite elbows there. I ordered two that I need for my vanity and I will test those with the shower as well and order more if they are OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ordering this https://www.rona.ca/en/aqua-dynamic-coupling-lead-free-brass-1-2-push-x-mip-9492-603-01735329?viewStore=55140 and it fits the shower compression adapter. not an elbow but thread wise it is the same thing

[image]