# What 90 degree push-in should I buy to work with this hose?

Tags: plumbing, fitting

I need to buy a 90 push in that has male NPT that matches this below hose end. I am not sure what to buy and if the 23-9/16" means 23" long hose and 9/16"ID for the compression fitting. What 90 push in fitting that works with this should I buy?

[image]

Update: This is a follow up or a sequel of [this thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222862/would-a-1-2x3-8-dishwasher-tube-to-pipe-elbow-90-take-a-3-8-flex-connect-for-a) where I was told not to use the fitting I was asking about because it is for a dishwasher and it will reduce the volume. So now I am trying to find the right 90 that would be push in on one end and it will take the above compression hose

Comment: What type of appliance is this, and can you post a picture of the hose end fitting with something in the pic for size reference. P.S.- in the U.S., "9/16" *is not a thing* as it regards plumbing fittings/sizes.

Comment: see the update please, click on the link for detailed pictures

Answer (score 1):

23-9/16" means 23 tpi and 9/16" in diameter - tpi is threads per inch.

Standard sizes so any decent hardware / plumbing store can help.

Comment: We are in lock down in Toronto -no decent store available to go to, I need to order online

Comment: For a better description of what you are looking for would be to tell us what that hose assembly is being used on. It looks like a hose set for a washing machine.

Comment: @d.george sorry I don't know exactly what those pipes are being used on, possibly a washing machine as they tend to have hot and cold water supply and most dishwashers only have a cold feed. Suggest you ask the OP as they will be sure to know.

Comment: those are used for the supply for a shower pannel This one https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/SH-PN-7001BN.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The hoses pictured in your previous (linked) post have a 1/2" NPT female thread (so stop worrying/commenting about the size of the line itself). Any fitting that will result in you having a 1/2" NPT male thread, will work.

Nobody can advise on the appropriate "push-in" connector because we don't know what you are trying to attach it to (what type of pipe). Find a fitting that connects to your supply pipe that will give you 1/2" NPT male thread.

Comment: That is the problem, I can't seem to find a 1/2" push in to what you call 1/2" NPT make.You have to admit the terminology is pretty lose here since you are telling me that it is an 1/2" npt but @Solar Mike explains that that 23-9/16" means 23 tpi and 9/16" in diameter so not exactly 1/2" I shop on Amazon.ca if you could show me such a fitting then I would admit I have some sort of blindness :-))

Comment: The terminology is not "loose"; you are getting different answers from different people. I don't care what the other answer(s) say, I am telling you that in the U.S., "9/16" is not a thing as it regards plumbing fittings/sizes. You can accept or ignore that but it is true. Also, unless you reveal what size and type of supply pipe you are looking to attach a "push-in" fitting to, nobody can help you find what you are looking for. Also, this is seeming more and more like a shopping question...

Comment: Not a shopping question. I am questioning here if the product even exist. I indicated in the above comment that the supply is 1/" -"I can't seem to find a 1/2" push in"

Comment: 1/2" what? Copper pipe, pvc pipe, steel/iron pipe, cpvc, other...?

Comment: Copper; does it matter from push-in perspective ? I was told it works on both